# php textbox autocomplete feature using javascript and postgres

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql

Does any one know how to implement auto complete feature in php using javascript and postgres db. I dont want to use ajax for this purpose.

Comment: Well it's pretty impossible without ajax (depending on the size of data you want to autocomplete)

Comment: What you will need for that is asynchrony - and you need Ajax ("_Asynchronous_ JavaScript and XML") for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you don't want to use XMLHttpRequest by saying that you **don't want to use AJAX**, there are another techniques to achieve same results. For example [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). You should be more specific in your question.

Comment: well I can explain in detail what I wana do

Comment: i have a postgres db and I want that when the user enters data in the textbox it should suggest data based on the values stored in the db.